Terraform azurerm backend is trying to use Key Based Auth to connect to blob storage even though use_msi=true is set
I am using terraform 0.12 and an azurerm backend to store my state configuration.
I am running into an issue where I have set use_msi=true via ARM_USE_MSI env variable and also disabled keys on blob storage per Azure's Recommended Policy to Prevent Shared Key Authorization (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/shared-key-authorization-prevent?source=recommendations&tabs=portal)
I am now running into an issue where when I run terraform init with my backend configuration file I am getting the error:
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: storage: service returned error: StatusCode=403, ErrorCode=KeyBasedAuthenticationNotPermitted, ErrorMessage=Key based authentication is not permitted on this storage account. 
When I enable Trace logging for terraform I see the following lines suggesting that the terraform is picking up the use_msi flag
2024/04/08 13:56:29 Testing if Service Principal / Client Certificate is applicable for Authentication..

2024/04/08 13:56:29 Testing if Multi Tenant Service Principal / Client Secret is applicable for Authentication..

2024/04/08 13:56:29 Testing if Service Principal / Client Secret is applicable for Authentication..

2024/04/08 13:56:29 Testing if Managed Service Identity is applicable for Authentication..

2024/04/08 13:56:29 Using Managed Service Identity for Authentication

...
Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically

use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.


2024/04/08 13:56:29 [DEBUG] Building the Blob Client from an Access Token (using user credentials)

...

API Call to storageAccounts/<redacted>/listKeys using the "access_token". 



The last API call returns the 2 Keys for the storage account. At this point I am questioning why the backend is trying to use the keys for the storage account to access it when I said that I want to use the the MSI.
The access token when decoded contains the appropriate claims that include the correct client id of the MSI and I have also ensured this MSI has all appropriate access to the blob storage.
Can anybody help point out where I have gone wrong in my configuration and why terraform backend is still trying to use the Key Based auth to connect to the storage account.
Using terraform 0.12 used azurerm backend with ARM_USE_MSI=true environment variable set and all other required env variables for use_msi to work https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm

Ensure that you are using a compatible version of the azurerm provider. The use_msi feature for the backend was introduced in version 1.44.0 of the provider.Make sure you are using version 1.44.0 or later

Double-check that the MSI has the necessary permissions on the storage account and that there are no conflicting access policies or firewall rules.

You need to use use_azuread_auth=true as part of your backend configuration which is available starting from Terraform v0.15.?
I was able to get this to work using Terraform v0.15.5

I used the following setup for my azurerm (logged in with my azure account, with the az login command before running any terraform commands).
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
  }
  subscription_id     = local.subscription_id
  tenant_id           = local.tenant_id
  storage_use_azuread = true
}

and the following backend configuration:
  backend "azurerm" {

    storage_account_name = "<name>"
    resource_group_name  = "<name>"
    container_name       = "<name>"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    use_azuread_auth     = true

  }


I had similar issue, so here what I did to make the whole thing worked without sas token:

setup the storage account you would like to use for storing backend state  files correct:


create a new resource group: MyBackendResourceGroup
Azure storage account: MyBackendStorageAccount
blob: default
container: state, ensure you have: Authentication method: Microsoft Entra user account
Give yourself (or your team security group) storage data contributor role on the storage account
1.1. if you have/want a azure devops pipeline then obviously you need a service connection to access this storage account to run terraform commands from the pipeline, so here you also need to create a managed identity


then in your terraform code, you need to have azurerm provider backend config like this:

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
      resource_group_name  = "MyBackendResourceGroup"
      storage_account_name = "MyBackendStorageAccount" 
      container_name       = "state" 
      key                  = "infrastructure"
      use_azuread_auth     = true
      use_oidc             = true
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


Then do the rest, if you needto run it locally, you need to follow this:
az login # use your normal account to login
az account set --subscription MySubscription
terraform init  # use passing bakend config, if you have fx different stoarge account for diff env: -backend-config="resource_group_name=MyBackendResourceGroup" -backend-config="storage_account_name=MyBackendStorageAccount"
terraform plan -out main-development.tfplan -var-file development.tfvars
terraform apply main-development.tfplan 

That should work locally.
Now If you need to do it from the azure pipeline, first you need to create a service connection for that managed identity you have created, ensure you are using recommended way which is to create workload identity federation
then you can have your pipeline template similar to this:
parameters: 
  - name: preInitTaskList
    displayName: The list of all custom tasks that need to happen before terrafom init command
    type: stepList
    default: [ ]

  - name: azureServiceConnection
    displayName: The name of azure service connection that has access to terraform backend
    type: string

  - name: terraformResourceGroupName
    displayName: The name of resource group that terraform backend storage account is located
    type: string

  - name: terraformStorageAccountName
    displayName: The name of terraform backend storage account
    type: string

  - name: terraformContainerName
    displayName: The name of terraform container
    type: string

  - name: terraformWorkingDirectory
    displayName: The path to root dir of the terraform main file
    type: string

  - name: terraformStateName
    displayName: The name of terraform state, it is the key in az container, and by default the same name as repository name
    type: string
    default: $(Build.Repository.Name) 

  - name: prePlanTaskList
    displayName: The list of all custom tasks that need to happen before terraform plan
    type: stepList
    default: [ ]

  - name: preApplyTaskList
    displayName: The list of all custom tasks that need to happen before terraform apply
    type: stepList
    default: [ ]

  - name: variableFileName 
    displayName: The name of tfvars file to be used 
    type: string 

  - name: setSingleVariableCommandOptions 
    displayName: The series of -var variable=value options to set variables coming from pipeline
    type: string 
    default: ''

  - name: outputNameList
    displayName: The list of the name of all output that needed to be exposed as pipeline variable 
    type: object
    default: [ ]

steps:
- ${{ if ne(length(parameters.preInitTaskList), 0) }}:
  - ${{ parameters.preInitTaskList }}

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: Terraform Init
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'init'
    workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}
    backendServiceArm: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
    backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.terraformResourceGroupName }} 
    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: ${{ parameters.terraformStorageAccountName }}
    backendAzureRmContainerName: ${{ parameters.terraformContainerName }}
    backendAzureRmKey: ${{ parameters.terraformStateName }}

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: Terraform Validate
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'validate'
    workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}

- ${{ if ne(length(parameters.prePlanTaskList), 0) }}:
  - ${{ parameters.prePlanTaskList }}

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: Terraform Plan
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'plan'
    workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}
    commandOptions: '-out=main-${{ parameters.variableFileName }}.tfplan -var-file=${{ parameters.variableFileName }}.tfvars ${{ parameters.setSingleVariableCommandOptions }}'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}

- ${{ if ne(length(parameters.preApplyTaskList), 0) }}:
  - ${{ parameters.preApplyTaskList }}

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: Terraform Apply
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'apply'
    workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}
    commandOptions: 'main-${{ parameters.variableFileName }}.tfplan'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}

- ${{ each output in parameters.outputNameList }}:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Output ${{ output }}
    name: output_${{ output }}
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        $env:ARM_USE_AZUREAD = 'true'
        $env:ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = $(az account show --query id --output tsv)
        $env:ARM_TENANT_ID = $env:tenantId
        $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID = $env:servicePrincipalId
        $env:ARM_USE_OIDC = 'true'
        $env:ARM_OIDC_TOKEN = $env:idToken
        $val = $(terraform output ${{ output }})
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=value;isOutput=true]$val"

